# ZooKeeper not getting started

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am facing issue while starting zookeeper.
zoo.cfg file is

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeperdata/1
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

I don't see any error while starting zookeeper :

```
nohup ./bin/zkServer.sh start zoo.cfg
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

could see a new process Id also :

```
cat /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeperdata/1/zookeeper_server.pid 
14120
```

But while checking the status of the process, getting below error:

```
bin/zkServer.sh status
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running
```

Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

This means that you're setting up a ZooKeeper ensemble, and one of the rules for a zk-ensamble is that the servers needs to form a majority before they are allowed to answer requests. This means that a zk-server is not running until it has formed a majority.

To get an informative answer from `status` you need to have at least 2 out of 3 servers running for a 3 server ensemble. Either remove these lines from your config or start another server. (And make sure the servers have different 'dataDir' and 'myid'.)

(Something a lot of people misunderstand is that the majority that is necessary is not a majority among the started servers but a majority among the servers in the configuration.)

Comment: I have 3 solrCloud instances on port 2888:3888 , 2889:3889 and 2890:3890. still getting same error. Got below error from zookeeper.out :

Comment: cat zookeeper.out 
2016-03-17 13:37:52,597 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2016-03-17 13:37:52,601 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@340] - Defaulting to majority quorums
2016-03-17 13:37:52,602 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@85] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
 at

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeperdata/1/myid file is missing
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:350)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:119)
 ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally

Comment: `/Users/admin/Documents/delete/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.6/zookeeperdata/1/myid file is missing`
That's why I said, make sure the servers have `myid`. 

**You attribute the server id to each machine by creating a file named myid, one for each server, which resides in that server's data directory, as specified by the configuration file parameter dataDir.** From https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperAdmin.html